# Float division issue in Python (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, math, equation, calculation

I'm working on a program which uses inputs from a tkinter interface to calculate the relative funniness of a joke based on sciencewritenow.com's formula:

`H ≥ ((((T1 + T2) / (T3 – R)) × I ) / D = ((T3 / T4) × S)) × B`

While I haven't encountered too many problems, whenever I input the numbers and hit the button to calculate the humour, I get the following error:

```py
H = (((float(T1.get()) + (float(T2.get()) * 0.1)) / (float(T3.get()) - float(R.get())) * float(I.get())) / float(D)) * float(B)
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

I guess it's pretty self-explanatory: the formula is trying to divide something by zero at some point in the program. The issue is that I didn't input 0 at any point in the program, and I don't think that any of the calculations should total zero. So, unless python has an issue with me inputing decimals like *0.33* (which it shouldn't, since I converted all the variables to floats), then I don't see what the issue is.

Here's my code (You can probably ignore the bottom half of the program, because I doubt that the issue is there:

```
import tkinter as tk

H = 0

# H ==> humour (greater than/equal to 1 = successful)
# T1 ==> tragedy (1-10, increasing)
# T2 ==> time (0.1 = 1 month)
# T3 ==> topicality (1-10, increasing)
# R ==> risk of recurrence (1-5, decreasing)
# I ==> immmunity (0, 0.025, 0.5, 0.75, 1)
# D ==> delivery ((T3 / T4) × S)) × B
# T4 ==> timing (0.5 = fast, 1 = slow)
# T5 ==> tone (0.33 = serious, 0.66 = conversational, 0.99 = lighthearted)
# S ==> shock value (1-3, increasing)
# B ==> bastard effect (0.5, unchanging)

def addNums():
    D = ((float(T4.get()) / float(T5.get())) * float(S.get()))
    
    H = (((float(T1.get()) + (float(T2.get()) * 0.1)) / (float(T3.get()) - float(R.get())) * float(I.get())) / float(D)) * float(B)
    
    print(H)
    
    result = tk.Label(text=(str(H), "funnies"))
    result.pack()

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("The Funny Formula")
window.geometry("300x300")

header = tk.Label(text="Input the level of tragedy (1-10)")
header.pack()
T1 = tk.Entry(text = "")
T1.pack()

header = tk.Label(text="Input the amount of time since the tragedy (1 per month)")
header.pack()
T2 = tk.Entry(text = "")
T2.pack()

header = tk.Label(text="Input the topicality (1-10)")
header.pack()
T3 = tk.Entry(text = "")
T3.pack()

header = tk.Label(text="Input the risk of recurrence (5-1)")
header.pack()
R = tk.Entry(text = "")
R.pack()

header = tk.Label(text="Input the immunity (0.25 intervals)")
header.pack()
I = tk.Entry(text = "")
I.pack()

header = tk.Label(text="Input the timing (0.5 = fast, 1 = slow)")
header.pack()
T4 = tk.Entry(text = "")
T4.pack()

header = tk.Label(text="Input the tone (0.33, 0.66, 0.99)")
header.pack()
T5 = tk.Entry(text = "")
T5.pack()

header = tk.Label(text="Input the shock value (1-3)")
header.pack()
S = tk.Entry(text = "")
S.pack()

B = 0.5


button1 = tk.Button(text='Find the funny', command=addNums)
button1.pack()


tk.mainloop()
```

I tried converting the variables to strings, which obviously didn't work and was a long shot. I also calculated the inputs manually on a calculator and couldn't find an issue.

Comment: But, maybe `(T3 – R)` is zero?

Comment: There are two divisors in that equation.  `T3 - R` and `D`.  Print them both, and see which one it is.  Is that not obvious?

Comment: You're so right @JohnGordon and quamrana. Turns out that I was idiot and every now and then T3 and R would be the same number, which would mean T3 - R = 0. I've added an if/else that changes the answer to 0.1 if it comes out as 0. Thanks so much for putting up with my dumbass-ness!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def addNums():
    print(T4.get(), T5.get(), S.get())
    D = ((float(T4.get()) / float(T5.get())) * float(S.get()))
    print(D)
    
    H = (((float(T1.get()) + (float(T2.get()) * 0.1)) / (float(T3.get()) - float(R.get())) * float(I.get())) / float(D)) * float(B)
    
    print(H)

    result = tk.Label(text=(str(H), "funnies"))
    result.pack()
```

Actually this error is basically "**float division by zero**". So actually when calculating H division is happening because D is calcualting on the basis of T4,T5 or S. Which seems that T4 value is divided by T5. So if T5 is zero than issue occurs.

Comment: @JRiggles, Thank you for your suggestion.   Actually this error is basically "float division by zero".  SO actually when calculating H division is happening because D is calcualting on the basis of T4,T5 or S. Which seems that T4 value is divided by T5. SO if T5 is zero than issue occurs. Actually if the answer is accepted that I was going to describe in details. But your suggestion will help me to answer in details.

Comment: @JRiggles, Yes I have added the info.